# Changing button .onclick, getting strange results (beginner)

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

I'm working on a text based game and am having trouble getting it started. It seems that the lines that are supposed to change the onclick function of the buttons (btn0 - btn3) in fight() are running those functions instead of simply changing the button functionality. I figured this out by adding alerts to the functions that are never called and seeing them pop up when the game starts, but the buttons are then lacking the ability to call the functions when clicked.

```js
var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
var textNode = document.createTextNode("You are accused of cosmic crimes by the GAMARO OF MAGNARAX. How do you plead?");
var gameText = document.getElementById("game");

var btn0 = document.getElementById("btn0"); 
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

var btn0_content = document.createTextNode("GUILTY"); 
var btn1_content = document.createTextNode("INNOCENT");
var btn2_content = document.createTextNode("");
var btn3_content = document.createTextNode("");

function start() {

    document.getElementById("start_button").style.display = "none";

    paragraph.appendChild(textNode);
    gameText.appendChild(paragraph);

    btn0.appendChild(btn0_content);
    btn1.appendChild(btn1_content);
    btn2.appendChild(btn2_content);
    btn3.appendChild(btn3_content);
}

var yourHPElement = document.getElementById("you");
var bossHPElement = document.getElementById("boss");
var yourHP = 100;
var bossHP = 1000;
var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
var hit = dice;

function fight() {

    btn0_content.textContent = "Attack";
    btn1_content.textContent = "Defend";
    btn2_content.textContent = "Item";
    btn3_content.textContent = "Inspect";

    yourHPElement.textContent = yourHP;
    bossHPElement.textContent = bossHP;

    rollBoss()

    gameText.children[1].textContent = "You are to be executed. You are struck for " + hit + " damage but did not fall.";    

    btn0.onclick = rollYours();
    btn1.onclick = defend();
    btn2.onclick = item();
    btn3.onclick = inspect();
}

function rollBoss() {
    yourHP = yourHP - hit;
    yourHPElement.textContent = yourHP;
}

function rollYours() {
    bossHP = bossHP - hit;
    bossHPElement.textContent = bossHP;
}

function defend() {
    alert("This feature not yet added.");
}

function item() {
    alert("This feature not yet added.");
}

function inspect() {
    alert("This feature not yet added.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CORRUPTED LAND</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./corrupted_land.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>CORRUPTED LAND</h1>
 <div id="game">
  <button type="button" id="start_button" onclick="start()">Start Game</button>
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" id="btn0" onclick="fight()"></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="fight()"></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" onclick="fight()"></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" onclick="fight()"></button>
 </div>
 <div id="hp">
  <span id="you"></span>
  <span id="boss"></span>
 </div>
<script src="corrupted_land.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding parentheses at the end of your onclick declarations you are invoking them.

So

```
btn0.onclick = rollYours();
```

needs to become

```
btn0.onclick = rollYours;
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something funny like that.